# error in module ipv4NetworkConfigurator, configurator module 'ipv4NetworkConfigurator' not found

Tags: omnet++

i am working in omnet++ for network simulation, i want to do a network client server with 2 routers as topology, i used the module ipv4NetworkConfigurator for assigning ip address automatically and routing table. But i can't understand the error 'ipv4NetworkConfigurator' not found

```
\\file ClientServeur.ned
 package networkclientserver.simulations;

 import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
 import inet.node.inet.Router;
 import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
 import ned.DatarateChannel;

   network ClientServer
  {
 submodules:
    Client: StandardHost {
        @display("p=56,154");
    }
    Server: StandardHost {
        @display("p=501,154;i=device/server");
    }
    R1: Router {
        @display("p=201,154");
    }
    R2: Router {
        @display("p=342,154");
    }
    Configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator {
        @display("p=251,62");
    }
   connections:
  Client.pppg++ <--> DatarateChannel {  delay = 100ms; datarate = 
  64kbps; } <--> R1.pppg++;
  R1.pppg++ <--> DatarateChannel {  delay = 100ms; datarate = 64kbps; } 
  <--> R2.pppg++;
  R2.pppg++ <--> DatarateChannel {  delay = 100ms; datarate = 64kbps; } 
  <--> Server.pppg++;
 }

  \\File omnetpp.ini

   network = ClientServer
   description = "Fully automatic IP address assignment"
   # Configurator settings
   tkenv-plugin-path = ../../../etc/plugins
   record-eventlog = true

   **.networkLayer.configurator.networkConfiguratorModule = 
   "Ipv4networkconfigurator"                  
   **.channel.throughput.result-recording-modes = all

   *.Configurator.dumpAddresses = true
   *.Configurator.dumpTopology = true
   *.Configurator.dumpLinks = true
   *.Configurator.dumpRoutes = true

   # Routing settings
   *.*.ipv4.arp.typename = "GlobalArp"
   #*.*.ipv4.routingTable.netmaskRoutes= ""
   sim-time-limit = 100s

   **.tcpType = "TCP"

   **.Client.numTcpApps = 1
   **.Client.tcpApp[*].typename = "TCPSessionApp"
   **.Client.tcpApp[*].connectAddress = "server"
   **.Client.tcpApp[*].connectPort = 80
   **.Client.tcpApp[*].sendBytes = 10MiB

   **.Server.numTcpApps = 1
   **.Server.tcpApp[*].typename = "TCPSinkApp"
   **.Server.tcpApp[*].localAddress = ""
   **.Server.tcpApp[*].localPort = 80

   **.tcpApp[*].dataTransferMode = "object"

   **.R1.ppp[*].queueType ="DropTailQueue"
   **.R1.ppp[*].queue.frameCapacity = 10

   **.ppp[*].numOutputHooks = 1
   **.ppp[*].outputHook[*].typename = "ThruputMeter"

   \\end file
```

error in module (inet::IPv4NodeConfigurator), Configurator module 'ipv4NetworkConfigurator' not found

Comment: Please do not edit other person answer to include your own answer.  If you found the solution, you are welcome to publish it as your own answer (you can answer your own question the same way as answering another person question). I recommend you to go on [tour] around the site and read [ask] and [answer] to learn how to write good questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

By default all the nodes expect that the configurator is called `configurator` (starts with lowercase), while you have

```
v
Configurator: IPv4NetworkConfigurator
^
```

where it starts with uppercase. As a convention it is recommended to start module names, types, interface names with uppercase, while use lowercase names for parameters, gates and submodule names.

Comment: I changed 'configurator' with lowercase letter, but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Update your question with the new files and the error message as the new error message has definitely changed. Also specifying the omnet and inet version you are using could be helpful.

Comment: thank you very much Rudi, i edit the files a litte and with your advice (lowercase), the problem solved

Comment: omnet version 4.6, inet version 3.3.0, the problem is solved